# Exporting CSV in french language shows junk charcters

Tags: java, opencsv

I am having a problem in exporting a csv file using `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter`. I did something like:

`File file = File.createTempFile("UserDetails_", ".csv");
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"),
                    ',');`

and then when I exporting the .csv file, it shows the junk characters for french letters.[Data to be saved in the .csv are french characters].
But previously I was doing something like:

`CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));`, then it was perfectly showing all french characters in Windows environment, but in Prod environment[Linux] it was showing junks. So I thought to use the Character set `UTF-8` for the file format to be exported.

How can I get rid of the problem?
Please Suggest!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Hichamov: Yes..but it shows junks in Windows and Linux both.. :(

Comment: Seems like the linux environnement needs the lang packages for french

Comment: I am not sure but once I was told its a problem related to Windows

Comment: @Hichamov that does not matter; the JDK comes with its own encoding mappings

Comment: @NDeveloper when you print the content before writing it to a file, does it appear OK?

Comment: At the time I was doing Android developpement and was told that the problem is from the windows char formats in the csv, but maybe I am wrong

Comment: Can you show input and your current output? One man's junk may be another man's Clew.

Comment: @fge: Yes before writing to .csv its ok!

Comment: @NDeveloper, Is your Java version 7, how could u fic this issue please? I too face the same issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothesis: you use Excel to open your CSVs under Windows.

Unfortunately for you, Excel is crap at reading UTF-8. Even though it should not be required, Excel expects to have a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the CSV if it uses any UTF-* encoding, otherwise it will try and read it using Windows 1252!

Solution? Errr... Don't use Excel?

Anyway, with your old way:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

this would use the JVM's default encoding; this is windows-1252 under Windows and UTF-8 under Linux.

Note that Apache's commons-io has `BOM{Input,Output}Stream` classes which may help you here.

Another solution would be (ewwww) to always read/write using Windows-1252.

Other note: if you use Java 7, use the `Files.newBuffered{Reader,Writer}()` methods -- and the try-with-resources statement.